# Appending output command to PHP CLI

Tags: php, bash, cron

So I am running a Crontab and I am unable to use environment variable when trying to run a PHP command with parameters.

The variable I normally run in linux is...

```
php ./run.php July 2014
```

However, I need to get the previous months date from a bash script, the bash script I am using is...

```
date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +"%B %Y"
```

That currently displays 'July 2014'.

I want to append that command to the end of the php command I am executing so that the parameters appear at the end of the command.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From memory you should be able to run

```
php ./run.php `date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +"%B %Y"`
```

The backticks will execute first to give you the value you need.

Sorry I cannot test this before posting.

Comment: Wasn't aware of this, thanks for the solution. Will give rep.